# Behaviour of NumberLong in Mongo Shell

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I wrote the following 4 statements in the Mongo Shell

i) `NumberLong(3)`

ii) `NumberLong(3)+NumberLong(4)`

iii) `typeof NumberLong(3)`

iv) `typeof (NumberLong(3)+NumberLong(4))`

and their corresponding outputs were

i) `NumberLong(3)`

ii) `7`

iii) `object`

iv) `number`

Although the second result makes the fourth one obvious, I am not able to get to the head or tail of this behaviour.What is happening behind the scenes?? I tried finding the underlying concept in the MongoDB documentation but couldn't find much. Please Help!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### What's the difference between Number and NumberLong?

JavaScript currently only has a single numeric type which is [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number), represented as an IEEE 754 double-precision floating point value (8 bytes).

MongoDB's [BSON storage representation](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification) has more numeric types than JavaScript, including 32-bit signed integers (4 bytes) and 64-bit signed integers (8 bytes).

The `NumberInt()` and `NumberLong()` constructors are [data types in the `mongo` shell](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/shell-types/#numberlong) that allow you to create integer values rather than using JavaScript's default floating point number.  These are implemented as custom prototypes so the `typeof` these will be `object` (as opposed to `number` which is part of the JavaScript primitive types).

When you add `NumberLong()` or `NumberInt()` values together, JavaScript coerces the result into the native `number` type which is why your results in the 2nd and 4th test differ from the 1st and 3rd.

#### Why use NumberLong / NumberInt?

These types are used to provide an interface to MongoDB's underlying BSON storage format.

A 32-bit integer (`NumberInt`) can be represented in half the bytes as compared to a `Number` or `NumberLong`.

A 64-bit integer (`NumberLong`) has more precision for large integer values as compared to a `Number`.  Since a double-precision floating point representation [reserves some bits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64) for the exponent, the largest `Number` that can be precisely stored is 2<sup>53</sup> versus 2<sup>63</sup>-1 for a `NumberLong`.

Comment: Ahhhh...Was about to offer a bounty for this...you came in at the right time and saved me...:) Thanks..